# AngularJS - Using a comma or other special character in expression to watch with $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, parsing, angularjs-scope, watch, angular-directive

I have a directive that was written a while ago and has been used throughout my application. I have now realised that it needs a watch so it can refresh and update when the value changes.

This is an attribute directive to apply Angular's ngIf directive depending on a user's authorisations. Used in the HTML it looks something like:

```
<div auth-if="id=12345;CREATE,READ,UPDATE"></div>
```

The problem I have is with the commas - when I try and watch the attribute value of authIf I get an error

**Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token**

Right now I don't know why I didn't just use the letters CRUD but I don't want to change what the directive accepts and potentially break things or cause confusion, etc.

So I was wondering if there is way for me make Angular be happy with the commas?

Here is a simplified version of my directive:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("authIf", ["ngIfDirective", "IsAuthorised", function(ngIfDirective, IsAuthorised)
{
    var ngIf = ngIfDirective[0];

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        priority: ngIf.priority - 1,
        terminal: ngIf.terminal,
        transclude: ngIf.transclude,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            var permitted = false;
            // run angular ngIf functionality
            attrs.ngIf = function() {
                return permitted;
            };
            ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, arguments);

            scope.$watch(attrs.authIf, checkAuth);
            function checkAuth() {
                /** check goes here
                    permitted = IsAuthorised(...); **/
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Try [`attrs.$observe`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) instead of `scope.$watch`

Comment: `id=12345;CREATE,READ,UPDATE` is not a valid [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: attrs.$observe only works for interpolated values I think... I did give it a try and it doesn't run when there is a change

Comment: attrs.$observe should do it. But you will only notice changes if you use interpolations, such as `auth-if="{{myModel}}"`

Comment: But wouldn't that mean updating all the places where this directive has been used? That is what I am trying to avoid, I am hoping there is some change I can just make inside the directive code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `attrs.authIf` is invalid expression you may wrap it in a function

```
scope.$watch(function() { return attrs.authIf; }, checkAuth);
```

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QJg1uMMBJrSkhGTt6yU5?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
      angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.dir = 'initial value';
        })
        .directive('dir', function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.$watch(function() {
                return attrs.dir;
              }, function(newValue) {
                scope.custom = 'custom ' + newValue;
              });
            }
          };
        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div dir="id=12345;CREATE,READ,UPDATE">
      {{ custom }}
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div dir="{{ dir }}">
      {{ custom }}
    </div>

    <input type="text" ng-model="dir">
  </body>
</html>
```